# forward-declaration, embedded classes and two .hpp including each other: how to use?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

When I was compiling the following, I got a `error: unknown type name 'ClassA'; did you mean 'ClassB'?`.

I guessed that my compiler needed to know **ClassA** to know **ClassB**, but it also needed to know **ClassB** in order to know **ClassA**.

So I tried **forward declarations** (like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/628079/3156085)).

For instance I declared `class ClassA;` before `#include "ClassB.hpp"` in my *ClassA.hpp*. And it worked fine!

**But there are still errors in case my classes use embedded classes declaration like right bellow :**

```
 error: incomplete type 'ClassA' named in nested name specifier
class   ClassA::ClassC;
        ^~~~~~~~
```

In this case I tried to declare `ClassC` in `ClassA`, to use `ClassA::ClassC` in `ClassB` and to add `class ClassA::ClassC;` before `#include "ClassB.h"` in *ClassA.h* (Some of these lines are commented).
But it doesn't do the job.

### My files :

I have 5 files :

- ClassA.hpp
- ClassA.cpp
- ClassB.hpp
- ClassB.cpp
- main.cpp

*ClassA* and *ClassB* respectivly contain `class ClassA` and `class ClassA` declarations.

**They both include each other.**

*main.cpp* include both *ClassA.hpp* and *ClassB.hpp*.

## Here is the content of my files :

**ClassA.hpp :**

```
#ifndef CLASSA_HPP
# define CLASSA_HPP

class    ClassA;
//class    ClassA::ClassC;      //<----- This doesn't work.
# include "ClassB.hpp"

class   ClassA{
public:
    // [...]
    void        printb(ClassB const & b) const;

    //class    ClassC{
    //};

private:
    // [...]
};

#endif
```

**ClassA.cpp :**

```
#include "ClassA.hpp"

void            printb(ClassB const & b) const{
    // [...]
}
```

**ClassB.hpp :**

```
#ifndef CLASSB_HPP
# define CLASSB_HPP

class    ClassB;
# include "ClassA.hpp"

class   ClassB{
public:
    // [...]
    void        printa(ClassA const & a) const;
    // ClassA::ClassC &    returnC(ClassA::ClassC elem);
private:
    // [...]
};

#endif
```

**ClassB.cpp :**

```
#include "ClassB.hpp"

void            printa(ClassA const & a) const{
    // [...]
}
```

**main.cpp :**

```
#include "ClassA.hpp"
#include "ClassB.hpp"

int     main(void){
    ClassA      a = ClassA();
    ClassB      b = ClassB();

    a.printb(b);
    b.printa(a);
    return 0;
}
```

## My question(s) :

In this case, using forward-declarations works for simple classes. But it looks like a workaround to me and it becomes a bit more complicated to use embedded classes and I don't really know how to handle this.

So:

- is there a better way (than forward declatation) to do such things?
- If not, how to do this using forward-declaration with embedded classes like this? What should I do instead of forward declaring `class ClassA::ClassC`?

Comment: You might also want to search for 'circular dependencies' for alternate solutions to your problem. Because, well, you have a circular dependency, which generally indicates a deeper design problem.

Comment: @ScottM That's true and I'm aware of that, but the homework I'm doing is designed that way. Though I discovered the embedded element I wanted to forward declare is an exception I use in a `throw()` statement in the declaration of a method in the other class. I just removed this *throw()* statement to make the error disappear but it seems dirty to me too. Anyway thank you for the help. :)